# Tika Solr Metadata mapping ignore document title

Tags: solr, metadata, apache-tika, solr-cell

I have the following config file for solr:

```
  <requestHandler name="/update/extract" 
                  startup="lazy"
                  class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <!-- All the main content goes into "text"... if you need to return
           the extracted text or do highlighting, use a stored field. -->
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">content</str>
      <str name="fmap.application_name">type</str>
      <str name="fmap.content_type">mime</str>
      <str name="fmap.stream_size">size</str>
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
      <str name="captureAttr">false</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

and this is my schema:

```
   <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="access_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
   <field name="access_restriction" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
   <field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
   <field name="content" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="created" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="createdby" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="modifiedby" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="source" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="version" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="resourcelink" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="downloadlink" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

   <field name="type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="mime" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
   <field name="size" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I want to set the `title` myself. But Tika keeps setting it's own `title` (that's why I set `multiValued="true"` temporarily), which I find strange because I have to manually map stuff like `stream_size` and `content_type`.

What solution is possible to this issue?

I'd like Tika to override the `title` I assign, like this:

I have 3 documents, for one of those, Tika doesn't extract a `title`, in this case, I have my own title I set passing `literal.title`, when Tika does extract a `title`, I want it to override the one I passed in `literal.title`. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you give the locations for solr config file and schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on the same issue some time ago, but I hit a wall as well :(
I let Tika take "title", and use literal.other_title_like_field to store proper title.
This is not a best solution, but worked for me.

Comment: Maybe you can give an example how to do this? Or a link about this?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used it for longer while now

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still struggling with this problem, I solved it by adding

```
<str name="fmap.title">ignored_</str>
```

in my ExtractingRequestHandler defaults.